# I am getting mysql_real_escape_string() function error while adding user?

Tags: users, mysql

I have written a code for inserting wordpress user if I try to add new user I am getting 3 warning errors saying like below:

"Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/intecom/public_html/app/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1129
" ,

"Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in /home/intecom/public_html/app/wp-includes/cache.php on line 725"

and

"Warning: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer in /home/intecom/public_html/app/wp-includes/cache.php on line 725".

my code is below:

```
  $first_name = 'my_firstname_value';
  $last_name = 'my_lastname_value';
  $trainer_email = 'trainer@example.com';
  $course_registered = Array
                      (
                        [0] => 2410
                      );
  $pro_icon_status = '1';
  $this->institute_icon[0] = '1';
  $this->institute_name[0] = 'my_institute_name';
  $user_data = array(
                    'user_login' => $first_name,
                    'user_pass' => '',
                    'user_email' => $trainer_email,
                    'first_name' => $first_name,
                    'last_name' => $last_name,
                    'role' => 'trainer'
                );
                $random_password = wp_generate_password(8,false);
                $user_id = wp_insert_user( $user_data );

                update_user_meta( $user_id, 'course_registered',$course_registered );
                update_user_meta( $user_id, 'inistitute_name',$this->institute_name[0] );
                update_user_meta( $user_id, 'inistitute_icon',$this->institute_icon[0] );
                update_user_meta( $user_id, 'trainer_icon',$pro_icon_status );
                wp_set_password($random_password, $user_id);
```

My input is only either string (or) array but why it is saying that "Iam passing object" I don't know what is happening. It is driving me nuts. can any one please tell me what was my mistake? Thanks in advance.

Update: The problem is not with 'wp_insert_user' or 'update_user_meta', actual problem is with the data that I was giving i.e. Am giving the same user_login name which is already there in the database, I am getting  the WP_Error Object as below:

```
  WP_Error Object
  (
    [errors] => Array
    (
        [existing_user_login] => Array
            (
                [0] => Sorry, that username already exists!
            )

    )

    [error_data] => Array
                  (
                  )

    )
```

Now can u plz tell me how to show that error to user on the front end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is from `wp_insert_user` and the fact that your value for `user_pass` is empty.

You should update your code as so

```
 $random_password = wp_generate_password(8,false);
 $user_data = array(
                'user_login' => $first_name,
                'user_pass' => $random_password,
                'user_email' => $trainer_email,
                'first_name' => $first_name,
                'last_name' => $last_name,
                'role' => 'trainer'
            );
```

And remove this line `wp_set_password($random_password, $user_id);`

You should also check the value of your `$user_id` to make sure it's not returning a **`WP_Error object`** 
You can use `var_dump($user_id')`

Comment: The problem is not with the user_pass field is empty, The actual problem with the WP_Error object as u said secondly. As I am trying to give the same username for 'firstname' field that is I am getting the error. Now can u plz tell me how to handle that error to show to the user if any error? Am updating Question with error.

Comment: @ Tunji Ayoola, Thanks, much appreciated ur efforts. as u said '$user_id' is returning 'WP_Error object' thats why I keep getting that error. since I am passing the same 'user_login' name I used before I got that error. I fixed it by replacing 'user_login' => $first_name, with  'user_login' => $trainer_email. I used 'trainer_email ' instead of '$first_name'.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use mysql_real_escape_string() without a link established to mysql. You have used the  mysql_real_escape_string() function before connecting to the mysql.

Comment: first, Thanks for your quick reply. You said "I have used the mysql_real_escape_string() function before connecting to the mysql." how I dont know could u plz tell me how and what should I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Hello you have to do some debugging on your code by making sure that all the variables passed to `update_user_meta()` are strings or arrays and not objects.

**FROM THE CODEX**

> The new desired value of the meta_key, which must be different from
>   the existing value. Arrays and objects will be automatically
>   serialized. Note that using objects may cause [this bug](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9640) to popup.

Comment: I am passing array only but I don't know why I am getting this error! I am writing the data which am passing to update_user_meta in my question above, plz check it once.

Comment: I am giving only string & array but I am not giving any object but why it was saying "I am passing object".  This is a basic thing but I don't know why it is not working. Please can any one help me..

Comment: @prasadchinthala Do you have `WP_DEBUG` turned on?

Comment: yes I tried that too but getting the same error, no better debugging.

Comment: just now came to know that actual problem is with 'wp_insert_user', for that I have posted a new question, plz check this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/249656/wp-insert-user-is-not-working-for-me

Comment: @prasadchinthala I've posted another answer