# wp_insert_user is not working for me?

Tags: users, mysql

I have written a code for inserting wordpress user if I try to add new user I am getting an error for wp_insert_user like below :

"Catchable fatal error:  Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /my/project/path/to/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin_name/plugin_file_name.php on line 5132"

If I echo return type of 'wp_insert_user' I am getting the above result. my code for wp_insert_user is below:

```
  $user_data = array(
                    'ID' => '',
                    'user_pass' => '',
                    'user_login' => $first_name,
                    'display_name' => $first_name.' '.$last_name,
                    'user_email' => $user_email,
                    'first_name' => $first_name,
                    'last_name' => $last_name,
                    'role' => 'my_user_role'
                );
                $random_password = wp_generate_password(8,false);
                $user_id = wp_insert_user( $user_data );
                echo "<pre>";
                echo $user_ id;
                echo "</pre>";
                wp_set_password($random_password, $user_id);
```

I did many advanced things with wordpress I know this is a basic thing but sometimes developers like me screwed with small things like this. I have been working on this for 3 days. Can anyone tell me whats wrong in my code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is from `wp_insert_user` and the fact that your value for `user_pass` is empty.

You should update your code as so

```
 $random_password = wp_generate_password(8,false);
 $user_data = array(
                'user_login' => $first_name,
                'user_pass' => $random_password,
                'user_email' => $trainer_email,
                'first_name' => $first_name,
                'last_name' => $last_name,
                'role' => 'trainer'
            );
```

And remove this line `wp_set_password($random_password, $user_id);`

You should also check the value of your `$user_id` to make sure it's not returning a **`WP_Error object`** 
You can use **`var_dump($user_id')`**